# Low Quality queue without options

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

> [image]

Again I got a deleted post in the queue. What shall I do there? Simply hit skip?

Guess that's a bug.

Now I hit the review "low quality" queue again and guess what: The answer apeared again...

> [image]

This time with a comment from another user.

Comment: As toscho commented below, this is how review queues currently behave - comments are disabled, so you shouldn't take that as an indicator that the answer is deleted. That was simply a coincidence.

Comment: If it is "status-bydesign", it is bad design.

Answer (score 5):

The post wasn’t deleted (I did that later), [comments are just disabled now in these queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198951/145551). Unfortunately.

I think this is not an improvement. We cannot tell the author how the post could be improved or why we gave a downvote.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshots, I can't even vote on that question/answer. Only possible actions are "Edit" and "Delete".

Comment: I second this defo being all but an improvement. However, I remember seeing the same recently and being able to right-click the question title, open in a new tab and comment/vote there. Don't see why SE would disable the functionality in-queue in the first place. Just saying that workaround was usable.